# A white screen flickers after displaying an image set to poster with a video tag

Tags: html, reactjs, html5-video

I am developing in React.
I'm playing a video using the Video tag, but the white screen flickers momentarily until the video is played after the image set in the poster is displayed.
How can I avoid flickering?

```
<video src="movie.mp4" poster="thumbnail.jpg" autoPlay controls playsInline muted></video>
```

Comment: is it a local video ?

Comment: thank you! it is not local video.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible ways to solve this:

1. Remove poster. Add background-image to video tag instead.

> ```
> background-image: url("first-frame-image.jpg");
> background-repeat: no-repeat;
> background-size: cover;
> background-position: center;
> ```

Con: your first-frame-image.jpg might look a little different color-wise (not size-wise) than the first frame of your video if you choose to use first-frame-image. You can still choose another image.

2. Add #t=0.1 to the end of your video src URL like so:

> ```
> <div id="videoContainer">
>     <video id="myVideo" playsinline loop muted onended="resetVideo()">
>         <source src="xxxx.mp4#t=0.1" type="video/mp4">
>         Your browser does not support the video tag.
>     </video>
> ```

What this does is take the frame at 0.1 seconds and places it as your placeholder/thumbnail.

Hope this helps!